# How to organize web services, so developers can easily find them?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

We're developping a software for a large bank. So, the problem is that bank operates in SOA way. I mean, we have an entry point to the system and then there are WebServices fow everything, and when I tell everything, I mean EVERYTHING, there are like 3500 services.

Right now these services are just stored in a database table with (or without, sometimes) their descriptions, so, you can imagine the hell we're living in. I guess that sometime it's easier to implement new web service than to find the right one, this produces redundancy.

So, my question is, is there some way of organizing this kind of stuff? I mean, we have many bussiness lines and some common components, but I'm totally newbie in WS. Anyway, I need some kind of way to provide the developers with information what service they can use in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen it done with a simple web site where developers can find descriptions, WSDLs, etc.  I think it's sufficient; I wouldn't recommend UDDI or buying a sophisticated tool.  Yours is a problem in advertising and marketing.

Answer (score 1):

A good documentation may help. Or google for the more sophisticated approaches like web service registries using WS-Inspection or UDDI.

Answer (score 0):

High Level Logic: Rethinking Software Reuse in the 21st Century

http://highlevellogic.blogspot.com/2010/09/high-level-logic-rethinking-software.html